# Capistrano: create tasks with roles did not work

Tags: ruby, capistrano

I try to create tasks with different roles :

```
namespace :foo do
  task :mytasks, :roles => [:a, :b,] do
    task_a
    task_b
  end

  task :task_a, :roles => :a do
    run 'echo A'
  end

  task :task_b, :roles => :b do
    run 'echo B'
  end
end
```

When i execute 'mytasks' here is the result :

```
$ cap -n ROLES=b foo:mytasks
  * 2013-03-01 16:59:14 executing `foo:mytasks'
  * executing "echo A"
  * executing "echo B"
```

All tasks get executed, why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Capistrano Roles](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/2.x-DSL-Configuration-Roles-Role) are intended to associate a given server (or multiple servers) with a particular function, such as saying "machine-a" is a web server while "machine-b" is a database server, which is useful because certain tasks only need to be performed on certain machines.

So roles are not intended to be a way to conditionally select which machine(s) to run tasks on at the time when you are running Capistrano, they simply select which tasks should be run on which machines.

There is, however, another Capistrano feature called [Multistage](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/2.x-Multistage-Extension) that may be what you're looking for. It allows you to specify different sets of servers (and even associate them with different roles) based on the "stage" you're deploying to. So you could have **a** and **b** stages, each with separate sets of servers, which you could deploy using:

```
cap a foo:mytasks
cap b foo:mytasks
```